# Some node in Kubernetes Cluster can't connect to K8S API Server and cause pods not function properly

Tags: kubernetes, networking

I got some strange problems and trying to fix it for a long time but failed.
Here is the thing:
Someday I found my Kubernetes cluster suffering with 3 nodes not ready, then I found that's bcz flannel pods failed on these nodes (I got 18 nodes in this cluster with 3 master nodes and kube-vip for Kubernetes API Server IP)
these flannel pods showed error: "Failed to create SubnetManager: error retrieving pod spec for 'kube-system/kube-flannel-ds-b2rbx': Get "https://10.96.0.1:443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kube-flannel-ds-b2rbx": dial tcp 10.96.0.1:443: i/o timeout"

First I try to fix flannel's problem by searching for this error message. Then I found it seems to be network related problem (though I know flannel is responsible for network too, it's kind of a chicken-and-egg problem). These are what I tested and results:

1. I create a new node and make it join the cluster, the new node and flannel pod on it works fine.
2. Restart kube-proxy, reset one of the buggy node and re-join the cluster, clear iptables, all these don't work.
3. Ping 10.06.0.1 OK.
4. Check iptables, buggy ones and normal ones look the same.
5. Check config in .kube and looks normal.
6. Executing `curl -k https://K8S-API-SERVER-IP:6443/version` and `curl -k https://K8S-API-SERVER-IP:6444/version` on buggy and normal ones, all the same responses.
7. Executing `curl -k https://10.96.0.1:443/version` on normal nodes, get same result as [6], but got time-out error on buggy ones.
8. Executing `traceroute 10.96.0.1` on buggy node got normal result. (1 record, all below 0.1ms)
9. Executing `telnet 10.96.0.1 443` on buggy node got `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`
10. no firewall enabled.

Any suggestions ?

Though I can just remove these 3 nodes and create brand new ones to join my k8s cluster, yet I still like to find out the root cause in case that it might happen again.